# Video source in conditional expressions

Tags: javascript, html, html5-video, conditional-statements

I'd like to know how to write a condition which includes the video source parameter(I'm using HTML5 and Javascript).

For instance, if video1 is playing (or loaded) and user presses 'W' key then video2 plays.

```
if(v.src=="video1.webm" && key_press=="Z")
        {
            v.src="video2.webm";
            v.play();
        }
```

But " v.src=='video1.webm' " doesn't seem to work. How can I use that expression in a condition?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Can you create a fiddle illustrating your issue? What _is_ v.src? does `key_press==z` evaluate to true?

Comment: Sure, thanks for helping out.
http://jsfiddle.net/ezmuU/

v = video
src = video tag source parameter.

PS: Key_press is working, when I press 'Z' the second video plays only if the condition is 

if(key_press=='Z')
{
   v.src="video2.webm";
   v.play();
}
But if I include v.src=="video1.webm" in the condition it doesn't work. It doesn't seem to recognize the expression.

Answer (score 0):

You must reload before playing it, if you update video source,

```
if (v.src=="video1.webm" && key_press=="Z") {
    v.src="video2.webm";
    v.load();        
    v.play();
}
```